# how to exclude out of stock in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have to display completely out of stock products in my table. Here Number 1 is In Stock and 2 is Out of Stock. Here I need to fetch only Out of stock (2) of product_id's, if any product_id at least one row has In stock (1) it will consider as In stock else consider as out of stock.

Please check here, I have tried this query but results not coming as expected

My [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75509d/5)

Comment: sqlfiddle "not found".

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75509d

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: It's best to also post code on stack overflow as well as sqlfiddle to allow future readers to see the code and understand your question. A number of us have clicked the link you gave yet have been unable to view the code.

Comment: I would edit the code in but someone jammed up the edit queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't understand 100% the question,
maybe this can help you.

this is the link to SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75509d/12/0

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM price p1
LEFT JOIN price p2
  ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id
  AND p2.stockstatus = 1
WHERE p1.stockstatus = 2
  AND p2.stockstatus IS NULL
ORDER BY p1.product_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

the out stock should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM `price` 
WHERE product_id not in (
       select product_id from `price`  where  stockstatus ='1') 
ORDER BY `product_id` ASC
```

Comment: `not in` is dangerous. Try never to use it. Especially on that query !

Comment: @drew .. why is dangerous?

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient I think

```
select * from price where product_id  NOT IN (select product_id from price where stockstatus = 1)
```

Also there is no need for apostrophes in table name. (If you plan on adding more stockstatuses consider adding `AND stockstatus = 2` after subquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stockstatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=innodb  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `stockstatus`) VALUES
(1, '100', 1000, '1');
INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `stockstatus`) VALUES
(2, '100', 500, '1');
INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `stockstatus`) VALUES
(3, '100', 800, '2');
INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `stockstatus`) VALUES
(4, '100', 700, '1');
INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `stockstatus`) VALUES
(5, '101', 700, '2');
INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `stockstatus`) VALUES
(6, '101', 699, '2');
INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `stockstatus`) VALUES
(7, '102', 700, '1');
INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `stockstatus`) VALUES
(8, '102', 699, '1');
*/

select  s.product_id, s.instock,
            case 
            when s.instock = 0 then 'Out of stock' 
            else 'In Stock'
            end as 'Status'
from
(
select product_id,
         max(case when stockstatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as instock
from price
group   by product_id
) s
where   s.instock = 0
;
```